# Outlook graph client applies a category to the message but it's not visible in UI

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm applying a category using graph client but sometimes (when I apply category for multiple messages in quick succession) it's not visible in the UI. When I do a get call for the message using graph client, I can see the category but it never shows up in outlook UI.
I've tried outlook/computer restart but no luck.

Comment: I have tested it in my environment. I have got the category in a proper way using both Graph Explorer and Graph SDK. Please open the message in a separate window by double clicking on it. And you will see the category. I didn't see it in the inbox tab list(message list), but if you open it individually you can get it.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, I see the category 99% of the times but issues occur when we modify the category for 10-20 messages in quick succession.
 If you apply any other category on this message from the UI, even the message fetched from the graph SDK removes the earlier attached category.

Comment: Can you please share us the requestid and timestamp where ever you think it didn't update?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, Category for following message is not available in UI but I can see it in the rest response "AAMkADY1OGNlMDU3LWRiMzItNGFlOC05NGYxLWFlNDkxZjA5NGMyYwBGAAAAAAAOffLdn8YzRJtNW_USHQfGBwABBtQinDHoTaK2icyOkMu9AAAAAAEJAAABBtQinDHoTaK2icyOkMu9AADGNtHTAAA=" and timestamp ` 2020-10-13T11:31:32.015+05:30`

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, Please give us the requestid which you get in the response header along with timestamp in the same response. We can't do anything with messageid.